# Used @BeforeTest of TestNG and @Before of Cucumber. But @BeforeTest is not hit when i execute my TestNG xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng, parallel-testing

Trying to do Parallel execution of all scenarios on multiple browsers. Many of the approaches tried failed. Have an option to create multiple feature files for Browser specific. In that way I will have to duplicate scenarios in each feature files. So trying to set browser name using @BeforeTest and use that in @Before of Cucumber so that I will trigger tests.

TestNG.xml --->

test name = ChromeTest
<class
parameter - chrome
class = testRunner.
classes -->

test name = firefoxTest
<class
parameter - firefox
class = testRunner.
classes -->

Hooks class -->

```
@BeforeTest - test ng annotation
@Parameters(browser)
method1()
set browser equal to browser
```

@Before - cucumber hoook
Trigger browser as per the value set in @BeforeTest

But @BeforeTest code is not executed.
Tried different approaches.

Comment: Let me check. the solution.